# trying to display Cards horizontally 3 items per row materia ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am pretty new to Material Ui and ReactJs. i am trying to display cards horizontally and each row has 3 cards. but now its currently displaying only 1 column.

this is a file that calls the cards

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Jobs from './Jobs'


const jobs1=[{
    company:"razer",
    jobtitle:"Data engineer",
   
},{
    company:"Huawei",
    jobtitle:"Data Engineer"
},{
    company:"Huawei",
    jobtitle:"Data Engineer"
}]
export default function Header() {
  return (
    jobs1.map((jobs1)=>(
        <Jobs jobs1={jobs1}/>
    )))
}
```

this is the cards file

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import img from './image/Razer.png'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import {Grid,Box } from '@mui/material'


const Jobs = ({jobs1: {company, jobtitle}})=>{
    return (
      
      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 300 }}>
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="100"
        sx={{ width: 100}}
        
        image={img}
        alt="razer"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography style={{color: '#bdbdbd'}}gutterBottom variant="h9" component="div">
        {company}
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="div">
        <Box sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
        {jobtitle}
          </Box>
        </Typography>
        <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" gap={14}>  
            <Typography sx={{fontStyle: 'italic'}} style={{color: '#bdbdbd'}}inline variant="body1"  align="left">
                1 minute ago
            </Typography>
            <Typography inline variant="body1" > 
            <Box sx={{ borderRadius: '12px', p: 1,opacity:"0.5", border: '0.5px solid',color: "#64dd17",bgcolor:"#ccff90" }}>Data</Box> 
                
            </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Typography  style={{color: '#bdbdbd'}}>____________________________</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      {/* <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">Share</Button>
        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
      </CardActions> */}
    </Card>
    
    
  );
}
export default Jobs;
```

i tried to do use the  and flexbox instead of printing out the items everything they delete all the items in the webpage instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your parent component in **Grid**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Jobs from './Jobs'
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';


const jobs1=[{
    company:"razer",
    jobtitle:"Data engineer",
   
},{
    company:"Huawei",
    jobtitle:"Data Engineer"
},{
    company:"Huawei",
    jobtitle:"Data Engineer"
}]
export default function Header() {
  return (
     <Grid container mt={2}  spacing={2}>
        jobs1.map((jobs1)=>(
           <Jobs jobs1={jobs1}/>
       ))
    </Grid>
 )
}
```

---

Next: Wrapping you child in **Grid**

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import img from './image/Razer.png'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import {Grid,Box } from '@mui/material'


const Jobs = ({jobs1: {company, jobtitle}})=>{
    return (
     <Grid item xs={4}>

      <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 300 }}>
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="100"
        sx={{ width: 100}}
        
        image={img}
        alt="razer"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography style={{color: '#bdbdbd'}}gutterBottom variant="h9" component="div">
        {company}
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="div">
        <Box sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
        {jobtitle}
          </Box>
        </Typography>
        <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" gap={14}>  
            <Typography sx={{fontStyle: 'italic'}} style={{color: '#bdbdbd'}}inline variant="body1"  align="left">
                1 minute ago
            </Typography>
            <Typography inline variant="body1" > 
            <Box sx={{ borderRadius: '12px', p: 1,opacity:"0.5", border: '0.5px solid',color: "#64dd17",bgcolor:"#ccff90" }}>Data</Box> 
                
            </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Typography  style={{color: '#bdbdbd'}}>____________________________</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      {/* <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">Share</Button>
        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
      </CardActions> */}
    </Card>

    </Grid>
    
  );
}
export default Jobs;
```

---

For more information you can check the [Grid System of MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/)